# Changes required for using non-quantized tflite files in MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, firebase, tensorflow, firebase-mlkit

This [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/mlkit-android/blob/master/custom-model/final/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/codelab/mlkit_custommodel/MainActivity.java) was written for quantised models and I'm trying to use unquantised model.

After making the changes as mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14719#issuecomment-348991399), [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/25b4086bb5ba1788ceb6032eda58348f6e20a71d/tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tflitecamerademo/ImageClassifierFloatInception.java) to [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/mlkit-android/blob/master/custom-model/final/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/codelab/mlkit_custommodel/MainActivity.java), my code is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private Button mRun;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Bitmap mSelectedImage;
    private GraphicOverlay mGraphicOverlay;
    // Max width (portrait mode)
    private Integer mImageMaxWidth;
    // Max height (portrait mode)
    private Integer mImageMaxHeight;
    private final String[] mFilePaths =
            new String[]{"mountain.jpg", "tennis.jpg","96580.jpg"};
    /**
     * Name of the model file hosted with Firebase.
     */
    private static final String HOSTED_MODEL_NAME = "mobilenet_v1_224_quant";
    private static final String LOCAL_MODEL_ASSET = "retrained_graph_mobilenet_1_224.tflite";
    /**
     * Name of the label file stored in Assets.
     */
    private static final String LABEL_PATH = "labels.txt";
    /**
     * Number of results to show in the UI.
     */
    private static final int RESULTS_TO_SHOW = 3;
    /**
     * Dimensions of inputs.
     */
    private static final int DIM_BATCH_SIZE = 1;
    private static final int DIM_PIXEL_SIZE = 3;
    private static final int DIM_IMG_SIZE_X = 224;
    private static final int DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y = 224;
    private static final int IMAGE_MEAN = 128;
    private static final float IMAGE_STD = 128.0f;
    /**
     * Labels corresponding to the output of the vision model.
     */
    private List<String> mLabelList;

    private final PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<String, Float>> sortedLabels =
            new PriorityQueue<>(
                    RESULTS_TO_SHOW,
                    new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Float>>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Float> o1, Map.Entry<String, Float>
                                o2) {
                            return (o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
                        }
                    });
    /* Preallocated buffers for storing image data. */
    private final int[] intValues = new int[DIM_IMG_SIZE_X * DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y];
    /**
     * An instance of the driver class to run model inference with Firebase.
     */
    private FirebaseModelInterpreter mInterpreter;
    /**
     * Data configuration of input & output data of model.
     */
    private FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions mDataOptions;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mGraphicOverlay = findViewById(R.id.graphic_overlay);
        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        Spinner dropdown = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mFilePaths.length; i++) {
            items.add("Image " + (i + 1));
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout
                .simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
        dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
        dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        mLabelList = loadLabelList(this);
        mRun = findViewById(R.id.button_run);
        mRun.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                runModelInference();
            }
        });

        int[] inputDims = {DIM_BATCH_SIZE, DIM_IMG_SIZE_X, DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y, DIM_PIXEL_SIZE};
        int[] outputDims = {DIM_BATCH_SIZE, mLabelList.size()};
        try {
            mDataOptions =
                    new FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions.Builder()
                            .setInputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, inputDims)
                            .setOutputFormat(0, FirebaseModelDataType.FLOAT32, outputDims)
                            .build();
            FirebaseModelDownloadConditions conditions = new FirebaseModelDownloadConditions
                    .Builder()
                    .requireWifi()
                    .build();
            FirebaseLocalModelSource localModelSource =
                    new FirebaseLocalModelSource.Builder("asset")
                            .setAssetFilePath(LOCAL_MODEL_ASSET).build();

            FirebaseCloudModelSource cloudSource = new FirebaseCloudModelSource.Builder
                    (HOSTED_MODEL_NAME)
                    .enableModelUpdates(true)
                    .setInitialDownloadConditions(conditions)
                    .setUpdatesDownloadConditions(conditions)  // You could also specify
                    // different conditions
                    // for updates
                    .build();
            FirebaseModelManager manager = FirebaseModelManager.getInstance();
            manager.registerLocalModelSource(localModelSource);
            manager.registerCloudModelSource(cloudSource);
            FirebaseModelOptions modelOptions =
                    new FirebaseModelOptions.Builder()
                            .setCloudModelName(HOSTED_MODEL_NAME)
                            .setLocalModelName("asset")
                            .build();
            mInterpreter = FirebaseModelInterpreter.getInstance(modelOptions);
        } catch (FirebaseMLException e) {
            showToast("Error while setting up the model");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void runModelInference() {
        if (mInterpreter == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Image classifier has not been initialized; Skipped.");
            return;
        }
        // Create input data.
        ByteBuffer imgData = convertBitmapToByteBuffer(mSelectedImage, mSelectedImage.getWidth(),
                mSelectedImage.getHeight());

        try {
            FirebaseModelInputs inputs = new FirebaseModelInputs.Builder().add(imgData).build();
            // Here's where the magic happens!!
            mInterpreter
                    .run(inputs, mDataOptions)
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            showToast("Error running model inference");
                        }
                    })
                    .continueWith(
                            new Continuation<FirebaseModelOutputs, List<String>>() {
                                @Override
                                public List<String> then(Task<FirebaseModelOutputs> task) {
                                    float[][] labelProbArray = task.getResult()
                                            .<float[][]>getOutput(0);
                                    List<String> topLabels = getTopLabels(labelProbArray);
                                    mGraphicOverlay.clear();
                                    GraphicOverlay.Graphic labelGraphic = new LabelGraphic
                                            (mGraphicOverlay, topLabels);
                                    mGraphicOverlay.add(labelGraphic);
                                    return topLabels;
                                }
                            });
        } catch (FirebaseMLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showToast("Error running model inference");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Gets the top labels in the results.
     */
    private synchronized List<String> getTopLabels(float[][] labelProbArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLabelList.size(); ++i) {
            sortedLabels.add(
                    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(mLabelList.get(i), (labelProbArray[0][i] )));
            if (sortedLabels.size() > RESULTS_TO_SHOW) {
                sortedLabels.poll();
            }
        }
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        final int size = sortedLabels.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            Map.Entry<String, Float> label = sortedLabels.poll();
            result.add(label.getKey() + ":" + label.getValue());
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "labels: " + result.toString());
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Reads label list from Assets.
     */
    private List<String> loadLabelList(Activity activity) {
        List<String> labelList = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader reader =
                     new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(activity.getAssets().open
                             (LABEL_PATH)))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                labelList.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read label list.", e);
        }
        return labelList;
    }

    /**
     * Writes Image data into a {@code ByteBuffer}.
     */
    private synchronized ByteBuffer convertBitmapToByteBuffer(
            Bitmap bitmap, int width, int height) {
        ByteBuffer imgData =
                ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                       4*DIM_BATCH_SIZE * DIM_IMG_SIZE_X * DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y * DIM_PIXEL_SIZE);

        imgData.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, DIM_IMG_SIZE_X, DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y,
                true);
        imgData.rewind();
        scaledBitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0,
                scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight());
        // Convert the image to int points.
        int pixel = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < DIM_IMG_SIZE_X; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y; ++j) {
                final int val = intValues[pixel++];
                imgData.putFloat((((val >> 16) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
                imgData.putFloat((((val >> 8) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
                imgData.putFloat(((val & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);


            }
        }
        return imgData;
    }

    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        mGraphicOverlay.clear();
        mSelectedImage = getBitmapFromAsset(this, mFilePaths[position]);
        if (mSelectedImage != null) {
            // Get the dimensions of the View
            Pair<Integer, Integer> targetedSize = getTargetedWidthHeight();

            int targetWidth = targetedSize.first;
            int maxHeight = targetedSize.second;

            // Determine how much to scale down the image
            float scaleFactor =
                    Math.max(
                            (float) mSelectedImage.getWidth() / (float) targetWidth,
                            (float) mSelectedImage.getHeight() / (float) maxHeight);

            Bitmap resizedBitmap =
                    Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                            mSelectedImage,
                            (int) (mSelectedImage.getWidth() / scaleFactor),
                            (int) (mSelectedImage.getHeight() / scaleFactor),
                            true);

            mImageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
            mSelectedImage = resizedBitmap;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    // Utility functions for loading and resizing images from app asset folder.
    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(Context context, String filePath) {
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

        InputStream is;
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            is = assetManager.open(filePath);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    // Returns max image width, always for portrait mode. Caller needs to swap width / height for
    // landscape mode.
    private Integer getImageMaxWidth() {
        if (mImageMaxWidth == null) {
            // Calculate the max width in portrait mode. This is done lazily since we need to
            // wait for a UI layout pass to get the right values. So delay it to first time image
            // rendering time.
            mImageMaxWidth = mImageView.getWidth();
        }

        return mImageMaxWidth;
    }

    // Returns max image height, always for portrait mode. Caller needs to swap width / height for
    // landscape mode.
    private Integer getImageMaxHeight() {
        if (mImageMaxHeight == null) {
            // Calculate the max width in portrait mode. This is done lazily since we need to
            // wait for a UI layout pass to get the right values. So delay it to first time image
            // rendering time.
            mImageMaxHeight =
                    mImageView.getHeight();
        }

        return mImageMaxHeight;
    }

    // Gets the targeted width / height.
    private Pair<Integer, Integer> getTargetedWidthHeight() {
        int targetWidth;
        int targetHeight;
        int maxWidthForPortraitMode = getImageMaxWidth();
        int maxHeightForPortraitMode = getImageMaxHeight();
        targetWidth = maxWidthForPortraitMode;
        targetHeight = maxHeightForPortraitMode;
        return new Pair<>(targetWidth, targetHeight);
    }
}
```

But I'm still getting `Failed to get input dimensions. 0-th input should have 268203 bytes, but found 1072812 bytes` for inception and `0-th input should have 150528 bytes, but found 602112 bytes` for mobilenet. So, a factor is `4` there always.

To see what I've changed, the output of `diff original.java changed.java` is: (Ignore the line numbers)

```
32a33,34
>     private static final int IMAGE_MEAN = 128;
>     private static final float IMAGE_STD = 128.0f;
150,151c152,153
<                                     byte[][] labelProbArray = task.getResult()
<                                             .<byte[][]>getOutput(0);
---
>                                     float[][] labelProbArray = task.getResult()
>                                             .<float[][]>getOutput(0);
170c172
<     private synchronized List<String> getTopLabels(byte[][] labelProbArray) {
---
>     private synchronized List<String> getTopLabels(float[][] labelProbArray) {
173,174c175
<                     new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(mLabelList.get(i), (labelProbArray[0][i] &
<                             0xff) / 255.0f));
---
>                     new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(mLabelList.get(i), (labelProbArray[0][i] )));
214c215,216
<                         DIM_BATCH_SIZE * DIM_IMG_SIZE_X * DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y * DIM_PIXEL_SIZE);
---
>                        4*DIM_BATCH_SIZE * DIM_IMG_SIZE_X * DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y * DIM_PIXEL_SIZE);
> 
226,228c228,232
<                 imgData.put((byte) ((val >> 16) & 0xFF));
<                 imgData.put((byte) ((val >> 8) & 0xFF));
<                 imgData.put((byte) (val & 0xFF));
---
>                 imgData.putFloat((((val >> 16) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
>                 imgData.putFloat((((val >> 8) & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
>                 imgData.putFloat(((val & 0xFF)-IMAGE_MEAN)/IMAGE_STD);
```

Comment: How is your imgData defined? That is where the issue likely is.  Also, an aside: in your question, can you just write two separate code snippets to illustrate the changes rather than intermingling them?

Comment: @PannagSanketi To see how `imgData` is defined, see `MainActivity.java`. I've made the question even more clear. Adding 2 separate codes increases the size of question. Thanks.

Comment: @duplex143 Like PannagSanketi suggested above, it's easier for us to comment if you paste all the code here in the question. Also, in the future, even if the code you linked to changed, other developers could still know the exact problem and possibly find an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @duplex143, I pasted one explanation to your imgData population logic. But if you still encounter problems, please paste your code snippet e2e including how you configure FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions.

Comment: @isabella-chen Also, as another question, I've replaced the `.tflite` and `.txt` files in assets with my files trained on another dataset. I've uploaded the custom model to the cloud as well. When I'm trying to predict an image from `StillImageActivity`,  why am I still getting the `ImageNet` labels? Does it not use the model from the cloud? Even after deleting the `ImageNet` tflite file from assets, why are `ImageNet` label predictions being made then? `Classification` in `LivePreviewActivity` is giving my custom labels though.

Comment: @duplex143, have you fixed your usage of float model?  Sounds like so? In the Quick Start app, StillImageActivity is only demonstrating Google's stock model of Image Labeling (Cloud Label /OD Labeler): https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/label-images In LivePreviewActivity, “Image Classification" is using custom model.

Comment: @duplex143 Change createImageProcessor() to use CustomImageClassifierProcessor. Feel free to file a bug on Github Quick Start repo for including custom model option into StillImageActivity

Comment: @isabella-chen Do lines 105 to 138 in [CustomImageClassifier.java](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/mlkit/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/samples/apps/mlkit/custommodel/CustomImageClassifier.java) or lines 164 to 179 in [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/mlkit-android/blob/master/custom-model/final/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/codelab/mlkit_custommodel/MainActivity.java) **not** load the model **from our project in Firebase**? Where is Google's stock model being loaded in CustomImageClassifier.java?

Comment: Sorry for mixing up [CustomImageClassifier.java](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/mlkit/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/samples/apps/mlkit/custommodel/CustomImageClassifier.java) and [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/mlkit-android/blob/master/custom-model/final/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/codelab/mlkit_custommodel/MainActivity.java). I was trying to make both of them work for unquantised models.

Comment: @duplex143 StillImageActivity is in Quick Start only. For quick start, I mean make the change to createImageProcessor() in this [file](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/mlkit/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/samples/apps/mlkit/StillImageActivity.java) . For the mlkit_custommodel code lab (MainActivity as you linked), that doesn't have any Google stock model examples and as long as you configure the right model name, it should work. If you have more questions on how to use Quick Start  / Codelab, file a Github issue and let's follow up there.

Comment: @isabella-chen I've added my findings as comments in answer. Kindly look into them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the buffer is allocated in the code lab:

```
ByteBuffer imgData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
    DIM_BATCH_SIZE * DIM_IMG_SIZE_X * DIM_IMG_SIZE_Y * DIM_PIXEL_SIZE);
```

DIM_BATCH_SIZE - A typical usage is for supporting batch processing (if the model supports it). In our sample and probably your test, you feed 1 image at a time and just keep it as 1.
DIM_PIXEL_SIZE - We set 3 in the code lab, which corresponds to r/g/b 1 byte each.

However, looks like you are using a float model. Then instead of one byte each for r/g/b, you use a float (4 bytes) to represent r/g/b each (you figured out this part already yourself). Then the buffer you allocated using above code is no longer sufficient.

You can follow example here for float models:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/25b4086bb5ba1788ceb6032eda58348f6e20a71d/tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tflitecamerademo/ImageClassifierFloatInception.java

To be exact on imgData population, below should be the formula for allocation:

```
ByteBuffer imgData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
    DIM_BATCH_SIZE * getImageSizeX() * getImageSizeY() * DIM_PIXEL_SIZE 
    * getNumBytesPerChannel());
```

getNumBytesPerChannel() should be 4 in your case.

---

[Update for the new question, in regards of below error]:

Failed to get input dimensions. 0-th input should have 268203 bytes, but found 1072812 bytes

This is the check that number of bytes expected by the model == number of bytes passed in. 268203 = 299 * 299 * 3 & 1072812 = 4 * 299 * 299 * 3. Looks like you are using a quantized model but fed it with data for float model. Could you double check the model you used? To make things simple, don't specify cloud model source and use local model from assets only.

---

[Update 0628, developer said they trained a float model]:

It could be your model is wrong; it could also be you have a Cloud model downloaded which overrides your local model. But the error message tells us that the model being loaded is NOT a float model.

To isolate the issue, I'd recommend below few testings:
1) Remove setCloudModelName / registerCloudModelSource from quick start app
2) Play with [official TFLite float model](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/25b4086bb5ba1788ceb6032eda58348f6e20a71d/tensorflow/contrib/lite/java/demo/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tflitecamerademo/ImageClassifierFloatInception.java)  You will have to download the model mentioned in comment and change Camera2BasicFragment to use that ImageClassifierFloatInception (instead of ImageClassifierQuantizedMobileNet)
3) Still use the same TFLite sample app, switch to your own trained model. Make sure to tune the image size to your values.

Comment: I'm still getting some error. I've updated the question.

Comment: I'm confused. I've generated the model file in `.pb` according to the script in [GoogleCodelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#3). I've converted it to `.lite` format using the script in [GoogleCodelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/#2).  I'm trying to use an unquantised model (inception/nasnet) here. See this flag in toco command `--input_data_type=FLOAT`

Comment: Too long to reply in comment. I updated the answer inline for troubleshooting recommendations.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'll let you know the findings of my testings.

Comment: I've tried using [inceptionv3_slim_2016.tflite](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/tflite/inception_v3_slim_2016_android_2017_11_10.zip) model file and removed the model from my project in cloud. Even then I'm getting `268203`, `1072812` error for V3. Have you gone thru the changes I made for MainActivity.java? I think something else needs to be changed there.

Comment: If possible, download the android [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/mlkit-android/tree/master/custom-model/final) and [inceptionv3_slim_2016.tflite](https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/tflite/inception_v3_slim_2016_android_2017_11_10.zip) model file, make changes to MainActivity.java I made, don't upload any model to project in Firebase and see if it's working.

Comment: @duplex143 I can try your usage (let's call it option #4)) next Monday, i.e. ML Kit code lab +  inceptionv3_slim_2016.tflite. But have you tried either 2) or 3)? (i.e. via TF Lite demo app).

Comment: I've tried both `2` and `3`. I've even tried on another official tflite app. To summarise all my findings, there are `2` tflite official apps [here](https://git.io/fNvs0)(the one you are saying) and [here](https://git.io/fNvsE). And I've `2` models (`mine` and `inceptionv3_slim_2016.tflite`). Both these `2` models are working for both the `2` official tflite apps. The `ML Kit code lab` isn't working for both my model and `inceptionv3_slim_2016.tflite`. So, if all the changes I made for [MainActivity.java](https://git.io/fNvsu) are correct, there's something wrong with ML Kit code lab. Thanks.

Comment: @duplex143, I see. Thanks for trying all combinations. I will take a look.

Comment: @duplex143, I just tried code lab with inceptionv3_slim_2016.tflite, it worked fine for me. The diff is here: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/mlkit-android/compare/master...isaisachen:patch-1#diff-e3cdf452fa5fcc7ff19a7bd0466b0ad2

Comment: I didn't change `BYTE` to `FLOAT32` in `dataOptions`. It's working now. Thanks for everything.

Comment: That should not be the case. Wrong dataOptions would fail much faster with data validation step. Your error message means right data input and wrong model. But anyways, glad to see it works for you now!